# Direct Transcription With Multibody Plant

Tags: drake

I am trying to solve a problem of moving a ball to a desired goal location. Currenlty I have the following code:

```
    plant = MultibodyPlant(time_step=0.01)
    scene_graph = SceneGraph()
    plant.RegisterAsSourceForSceneGraph(scene_graph)
    parser = Parser(plant)
    ConfigureParser(parser)
    parser.AddModelsFromString(minigolf_urdf, 'urdf')
    plant.Finalize()


    context = plant.CreateDefaultContext()
    dirtran = DirectTranscription(
        plant,
        context,
        400,
        input_port_index=plant.get_actuation_input_port().get_index(),
    )
    prog = dirtran()

    initial_state = (-2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    prog.AddBoundingBoxConstraint(
        initial_state, initial_state, dirtran.initial_state()
    )
    # More elegant version is blocked by drake #8315:
    # prog.AddLinearConstraint(dirtran.initial_state() == initial_state)

    final_state = (2.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0)
    prog.AddBoundingBoxConstraint(
        final_state, final_state, dirtran.final_state()
    )
    # prog.AddLinearConstraint(dirtran.final_state() == final_state)

    dirtran.AddConstraintToAllKnotPoints(dirtran.input()[0] <= 1)
    dirtran.AddConstraintToAllKnotPoints(dirtran.input()[1] <= 1)
    dirtran.AddConstraintToAllKnotPoints(dirtran.input()[0] >= -1)
    dirtran.AddConstraintToAllKnotPoints(dirtran.input()[1] >= -1)

    initial_x_trajectory = PiecewisePolynomial.FirstOrderHold(
        [0.0, 16.0], np.column_stack((initial_state, final_state))
    )  # yapf: disable
    dirtran.SetInitialTrajectory(PiecewisePolynomial(), initial_x_trajectory)

    result = Solve(prog)
```

The code was working completely correctly when I was using Direct Collocation, but no result can be found for Direct Transcription. The resulting trajectory is just the ball staying put. Is there any reason for this? The bounding box constraint is there and this is a very simple problem where the initial trajectory is already a valid solution. Could it be that discretizing the problem makes it not work?

My urdf is pasted below:

```
base_urdf = """
  <link name="base">

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="8 2 0.002" />
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <color rgba="0 1 0 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>

  </link>
"""

hole_urdf = """
  <link name="hole">

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="2 0.5 -0.024" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius=".05" />
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>

  </link>
"""

ball_urdf = """
  <link name="ball">

    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.051" />
      <mass value="1" />
    </inertial>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.051" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius=".05" />
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <color rgba="1 1 1 0" />
      </material>
    </visual>

  </link>
"""

mass = """
  <link name="mass">

    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.051" />
      <mass value="1" />
    </inertial>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.051" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius=".05" />
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <color rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>

  </link>
"""

base_joint = """
  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world" />
    <child link="base" />
  </joint>
"""

hole_joint = """
  <joint name="hole_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world" />
    <child link="hole" />
  </joint>
"""

ball_joint = """
  <joint name="ball_joint" type="prismatic">
    <parent link="base" />
    <child link="ball" />
    <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
  </joint>
"""

mass_joint = """
  <joint name="mass_joint" type="prismatic">
    <parent link="ball" />
    <child link="mass" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit effort="1" lower="0" upper="0" />
  </joint>
"""

ball_transmission = """
  <transmission type="SimpleTransmission" name="ball_force">
    <actuator name="ball_force" />
    <joint name="ball_joint" />
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </transmission>
"""

mass_transmission = """
  <transmission type="SimpleTransmission" name="mass_force">
    <actuator name="mass_force" />
    <joint name="mass_joint" />
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </transmission>
"""

minigolf_urdf = f"""
<?xml version="1.0"?><robot name="Minigolf">
    {base_urdf}
    {hole_urdf}
    {ball_urdf}
    {mass}
    {base_joint}
    {hole_joint}
    {ball_joint}
    {mass_joint}
    {ball_transmission}
    {mass_transmission}
    </robot>
</xml>
"""
```

Comment: Does your plant state include the orientation of the ball? What is the dimensionality of the state here? You can do `print(plant.num_positions())` and `print(plant.num_velocities())`.

Comment: I don't think so, both values are 2. How would I go about including that. Also it seems that only the x and y coordinates are included but how could I get a z coordinate in there?

Comment: Is it OK if you could paste your minigolf.urdf in the answer, so that we can reproduce your example? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, thanks! I have added it to the question post.

Comment: I also realized my plant does not seem to have a gravitational force. How can this be incorporated into a multibody plant?

Comment: There is no gravity because the ball joint is acting in the x axis and the mass joint is acting in the y axis (which seems strange that they are not in the same axes?).  gravity acts in z.

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
plant = MultibodyPlant(time_step=0.01)
```

to

```
plant = MultibodyPlant(time_step=0.1)
```

allows the problem to be solved. I believe you simply didn't have enough time to get from the initial state to the final state, given the input limits.